# How to create ViewController in my situation? ios7

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I got first `ViewController` with out navigation controller, I go from it to second `ViewController` via

```
if (!self.mapViewController)
{
   self.mapViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MapViewController"];
}
[self presentViewController:self.mapViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I send some data with `prepareForSegue` to it, but I need that it also be with  navigation controller.
I embed in a  navigation controller in storyboard but my code still called second `ViewController` with out navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give an identifier to the navigation controller in storyboard.  Instantiate and present that.

```
UINavigationController *navVC = [self.storyboard
    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TheNavVCWhoseRootIsMyMapViewController"];

self.mapViewController = navVC.viewControllers[0];  // your map vc is at the root
[self presentViewController:navVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not a professional with the way of the storyboard, however i believe that instead of `presentViewController`
you should be using the following function to present a storyboard VC based on segues.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueIdentifierHere" sender:nil];
```

Make sure that in your storyboard you have incorporated a UINavigationControllerVC as well.

Comment: I have no one Segue with first ViewController and  navigation controller of second ViewController

Comment: A good tutorial to look at would be here: 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Answer (score 0):

You are using `presentViewController:animated:completion` which will indeed display a `UIViewController` without the `UINavigationController` the previous `UIViewController` was embedded in.
Try using the following:

`[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.mapViewController animated:YES]`